# Can't get the value in an input with protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

I'm using angularJS to develop an application. To test it I use protractor.

I want to check the value in an input area. This is my input:

```
<input id="rank-max-range" class="form-control has-feedback" name="inputMax" type="number" placeholder="Maximum" ng-model="selectedItem.range.max" min="{{selectedItem.range.min}}" max="{{selectedItem.answers.length}}">
```

And this is the test:

```
it('should be fill the max range with the given value', function() {
  element(by.id('rank-max-range')).sendKeys(2);
  expect(element(by.id('rank-max-range')).getText()).toEqual(2);
});
```

The problem is it didn't work. I found on the documentation that it is possible to use `getAttribute('value')`. But in my case there is no value attribute on my input.

I wonder if it possible to check the content of the `ng-model` but I didn't find the solution.

Do you have an idea of how I could achieve this test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally `getAttribute('value')` should work. `getText()` won't work because input elements don't have inner text.

```
expect(element(by.id('rank-max-range')).getAttribute('value')).toEqual(2);
```

Have you tried to log the result of `getAttribute('value')`?

Answer (score 1):

`getText()` would not definitely work, since this is an `input` and it's value would be inside the `value` attribute, once set. The HTML you've presented does not contain `value` because this is a source HTML when the page is not rendered and the value is not set. `getAttribute('value')` is the way to go here:

```
var numberInput = element(by.id('rank-max-range'));
numberInput.sendKeys("2");
expect(numberInput.getAttribute('value')).toEqual("2");
```

You can actually see the `value` being set by dumping the [`innerHTML`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getInnerHtml) on the console:

```
numberInput.sendKeys("2");
numberInput.getInnerHtml().then(function (html) {
    console.log(html);
});
```

---

> I wonder if it possible to check the content of the ng-model but I didn't find the solution.

You can use [`evaluate()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.evaluate) to see/check the value of the model:

```
expect(numberInput.evaluate('selectedItem.range.max')).toEqual(2);
```

Comment: Indeed, it works. I tried this solution before but I certainly made a syntax mistake or something like that. Thank you. It helped me to understand how getAttribute works. Even with the doc I didn't fully understand.

Comment: @Mtoypc thank you, I think it makes sense to accept Thomas's answer - he was first to point out that `getAttribute('value')` should work.